# Select multiple defined sheets

Tags: excel, vba

This is a very basic question but I just can't get it right.
I have a workbook with multiple sheets, but for this code I only need two specific ones, which the user selects. So the code starts like this:

```
Dim SheetA as Worksheet
Dim SheetB as Worksheet

Set SheetA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("The sheet the user wants")
Set SheetB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("The sheet the user wants")
```

Then there is some code. Later I need to select these two sheets and I want the first sheet to be activated.
This is the code I've tried so far, but it does not work (at least the first line).

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(SheetA, SheetB)).Select
SheetA.Activate
```

Thank you for any helpful advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. However, the `Sheets`-collection needs numbers or strings as parameter, but in your code you are passing `Worksheet`-objects. The fix is easy: Just pass the names of the worksheets:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(SheetA.name, SheetB.name).Select
```